# How to add auto scroll for Entry placeholder?

Tags: xamarin.forms, autoscroll

I am using an Entry *(CustomEntry with no underline)* like below:

**Code:**

```xml
<renderer:CustomEntry
    x:Name="search_entry"
    Placeholder="Search by request id, requester's name, title, or description"
    Style="{StaticResource SearchEntryStyle}"/>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

The placeholder text is lengthy, so it's not possible to read the complete text of it. Is there any way to add an auto scroll for the Entry placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way to do this using the Entry control itself, e.g. with a custom renderer.

However, perhaps you can fake it by binding the `Placeholder` to a property in the code-behind or ViewModel and then update the text and make it look like it scrolls by removing the characters at the beginning one-by-one.

Here's a sample implementation with a timer which updates the placeholder every 200 milliseconds, but you can of course also do it differently:

## Xamarin.Forms

```cs
public class SomeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private const string Placeholder = "This is a very long text for a placeholder of an Entry that seems to be animated... ";

    private string _placeholderText = Placeholder;
    public string PlaceholderText
    {
        get => _placeholderText;
        set
        {
            if(_placeholderText == value) return;
            _placeholderText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200), () =>
        {
            var firstChar = PlaceholderText[0];
            var sb = new StringBuilder(PlaceholderText);
            sb.Remove(0, 1);
            sb.Append(firstChar);
            PlaceholderText = sb.ToString();

            return true;
        });        
    }

    //...
}
```

## .NET MAUI

In .NET MAUI, the implementation is essentially the same, except that you'll need to use a *DispatcherTimer* instead of the deprecated *DeviceTimer*:

```cs
public SomeViewModel()
{
    var timer = Application.Current.Dispatcher.CreateTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
    timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
    {
        var firstChar = PlaceholderText[0];
        var sb = new StringBuilder(PlaceholderText);
        sb.Remove(0, 1);
        sb.Append(firstChar);
        PlaceholderText = sb.ToString();
    };
    timer.Start();
}
```

## Binding the Placeholder

Then in your View, you can bind to the `PlaceholderText` property:

```xml
<renderer:CustomEntry
    x:Name="search_entry"
    Placeholder="{Binding PlaceholderText}"
    Style="{StaticResource SearchEntryStyle}"/>
```

Comment: I tried this and placeholder get a scrolling effect. But the very first letter is not showing in the UI, I resolved it by adding a blank space at the beginning.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u0wE.png

Comment: due to the above error I changed the code without dots `var substring = PlaceholderText[1];`

Comment: After closing the page, how we can stop the timer???

Comment: Where it says `return true;` in the timer callback, you can also return a variable instead, e.g. `return isRunning;` which you can set to `false` before closing the page.

Comment: what is the use of ..1???

Comment: `PlaceholderText[..1]` is a [range expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges) that says to take all elements from the start until the index (exclusive). So here that would be to take all elements before index 1, which would be only the first character. In your case, `PlaceholderText[0]` should be sufficient, indeed. The C# version you're using may not support that notation, I'll update the answer accordingly. It's a C# 8.0 feature. You can also enable C# 8.0 for Xamarin.Forms, if you wish.